# Oracle: Fuzzy lookup

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm loading a table looking up an employee table. However sometimes the names from Source files and Employee table does not match correctly.

```
**Employee table:**
Employee Name
Paul Jaymes

**Source File**
Paul James
```

I want this to match. What could be the solution.

Comment: The `SOUNDEX` function might help here.

Comment: If you are talking about loading the **CORRECT FILE** into the DB, I think that no "GUESSING" method should be used. Instead, make sure that the filenames perfectly match. Imagine what could be the result of wrong guesses... A new, very _green_ programmer named Peter Finch would be getting the CEO's salary because his name is Peter Fynch... (I'll be happy to be Peter Finch :-)!!!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`UTL_MATCH` package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_match.htm#ARPLS72002) or the [`SOUNDEX` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions148.htm):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03a9a/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( Name ) AS
SELECT 'Paul Jaymes' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

> `UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE`:
>   Calculates the number of changes required to transform string-1 into string-2

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employees
WHERE  UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE( Name, 'Paul James' ) < 2
```

**Query 2**:

> `UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY`:
>   Calculates the number of changes required to transform string-1 into string-2, returning a value between 0 (no match) and 100 (perfect match)

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employees
WHERE  UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY( Name, 'Paul James' ) > 90
```

**Query 3**:

> `UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER`:
>   Calculates the measure of agreement between string-1 and string-2

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employees
WHERE  UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER( Name, 'Paul James' ) > 0.9
```

**Query 4**:

> `UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY`:
>   Calculates the measure of agreement between string-1 and string-2, returning a value between 0 (no match) and 100 (perfect match)

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employees
WHERE  UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY( Name, 'Paul James' ) > 95
```

**Query 5**:

> `SOUNDEX`:
>   returns a character string containing the phonetic representation of char. This function lets you compare words that are spelled differently, but sound alike in English.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employees
WHERE  SOUNDEX( Name ) = SOUNDEX( 'Paul James' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03a9a/7/6)**:
All give the output:

```
|        NAME |
|-------------|
| Paul Jaymes |
```

Comment: The beauty of using `SOUNDEX()` is that you can use a function-based index which sadly isn't possible with the `UTL_MATCH` functions

Answer (score 1):

Use UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY function in Oracle.

I would recommend creating a temporary table as below and check if the data is as expected. Usually score above 90-93 should be same with some typo in different systems. If there's only difference in 1 character you would get a score of 92 and above.

```
select s.employee_name,
utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(initcap(s.employee_name),e.employee_name) as score
from source_table s cross join employee_table e
where utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(initcap(s.employee_name),e.employee_name) >=90 ;
```